# Error when trying to set scale_x_discrete and scale_y_discrete

Tags: r, ggplot2

I run the following code:

```
ggplot(pat, aes(y=CANCompany,x=USCompany,alpha=TotalPatents,
                size=SharedPatents,color = Revenue)) + 
theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.box.just="center",
      legend.key.size=unit(0.55,"cm")) + 
scale_size(range = c(0, 15)) + 
scale_colour_gradient(low="yellow", high="green4") + geom_point() +
theme(axis.text.x  = element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.5, size=10), 
      axis.text.y  = element_text(angle=0, vjust=0.5, size=10)) +
scale_x_discrete(position = "top") +
coord_fixed() +
theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

On the following data:(showing 1st 10 rows):

```
   CANCompany  USCompany SharedPatents Revenue TotalPatents
        <chr>      <chr>         <int>   <int>        <int>
1  Blackberry     Google             3      58           27
2  Blackberry        IBM             1      52           71
3  Blackberry      Apple             2     107           46
4  Blackberry   Lockheed            11      43           29
5  Blackberry CapitalOne             2     142           70
6  Blackberry      Merck             5      10           68
7  Bombardier     Google             8      89           34
8  Bombardier        IBM            12     100           24
9  Bombardier      Apple             4       8           29
10 Bombardier   Lockheed             5     134           53
```

I get the following plot:

[image]

I then add the two following lines to my code:

```
 + scale_x_discrete(limits=c("IBM","Merck","Lockheed","Google","Apple","CapitalOne")) + 
scale_y_discrete(limits=c("Bombardier","Iogen","Westport","Nortel","Mitel","Blackberry"))
```

And get the following errors:

> Scale for 'x' is already present. Adding another scale for 'x', which
>   will replace the existing scale.

Warning message:

> Removed 6 rows containing missing values (geom_point).

The plot now looks like this, after trying to reorder axis:

[image]

Is there a way to over-ride and set both x and y axis as I like?

Why does a row of the data disappear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning tells you that you used `scale_x_discrete` twice. Try deleting the first instance and adding `position = top` to the second instance.

You have a missing row because in `scale_y_discrete` you spelled "Westport" with a lower case 'p'. It looks from the first chart like it should be "WestPort".

In addition:

I'd also consider making your data *tidy*: have a column named "patent_type" (shared/not shared) and a column with patent numbers. Have a column named "country_location" (US or Canada) and another "company_name".

I don't know that a dot chart is the best choice for this data. Seems like you're trying to cram a lot of variables into one plot (*e.g.* using alpha for numbers is not the best choice).

Comment: Thanks!  As a 40+ learning R user error is a little more frequent than I would like.  I didn't think of the scale_x_discrete being there twice as an issue since I have theme there a few times as well. Cleaning up my code to be more efficient is my next step.  Taking the 'Data Camp' tutorial as well.        

With respect to the making the data tidy, one problem I see in your set-up, which I agree is simpler, is that I need to have the both companies identified for each shared patents.  So I think I need to have two columns for companies and as many rows as shared patent relationships.